# Different outputs in removing characters from a list - Python

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, character

I'm doing some web scraping in python and I want to delete the element "." from each element of a list. I have two approaches, but just one gives the correct output. The code is above.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
first=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/res20130914/A.html").read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(first)
w=[]
for q in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for link in q.find_all('a'):
        w.append(link["href"])

s = [ i.replace(".","") for i in w ]

l=[]

for t in w:
    l=t.replace(".","")
```

If I run `print s` , the output is the right output , but if I run `print l`, it isn't.

I would like to know why `s` gives the correct ouput and  `l` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop, you replace the whole list in each iteration, instead of appending to it as in the single line example.

Instead, try:

```
for t in w:
    l.append(t.replace(".",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the list each time and it'e getting overwritten. As a result, you are getting the last element after the iterations! Hope, it helps!

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
first=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/res20130914/A.html").read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(first)
w=[]
for q in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for link in q.find_all('a'):
        w.append(link["href"])

s = [ i.replace(".","") for i in w ]
print s
l=[]

for t in w:
    l.append(t.replace(".",""))
print l
```

Cheers!